# Is there an add on that can register the visual locrot of bones influences by IK?

Tags: add-on

So the bones will remain in place when Ik is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Select the bones you need and in pose mode go to the menu Pose_Animation_Bake action. Check Visual keying and clear constraints.

Comment: Well, is there other way without to loose my current dope sheet state.
After baking, the keyframe became in certain frame steps.

Comment: Actually, it turns out I can set which frame to be baked. So, yeah, it's one alternative to achieve what I need.